# How to determine missing font on MacOS

Tags: macos, firefox, macos-ventura

I'm having trouble reading some webpages on Firefox and MacOS. I commonly come across sites that look like the following.

Is it possible to determine which font is missing by inspecting the web page source or via web developer tools? The issue seems to be specifically related to Firefox as the fonts are loaded correctly with Chrome and Safari

Edit: Here is an [example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/5-things-founders-recruiters-should-know-cto-role-neerventure-com/?trk=public_post_feed-article-content)

[image]

Comment: What versions of Firefox and macOS are you using?

Comment: Interesting tidbit: This is what I've termed "the offset by 1 problem". You'll notice that the displayed glyphs are actually one away from what they should be: instead of the letter `M`, you get one away, or `N`. Thus, `My job` becomes `Nz!kpc`. I've seen this happen before with font conflicts dealing with the font `Times`, which is Firefox's default serif font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Alternative - Go into the browser console (Command + Option + I) and use the console selection pointer tool (icon to the left of under 'inspector' tab) and select a piece of text with the unknown font. Under the "Rules" panel where you will see all the CSS elements for the page, add to the body or paragraph element a definition "font-family:Arial" and see if this allows you to read the text.

Comment: Thanks @mann - this helped me identity that I didn't have a Google font installed on my system, specifically Source Serif Pro.